Gripper action controller showing aborted status ABORTED using mimic joints
I am trying to use the 5DoF Lynxmotion Robotic Arm, but I've not been able to use the gripper when I launch the robot simulation on Gazebo and try to use it with RViz.
Error:
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1727265626.544777193] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Controller handle gripper_action_controller reports status ABORTED
[rviz2-5] [ERROR] [1727265626.554387427] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::move() failed or timeout reached

Moveit controller configuration file:
controller_names:
  - arm_trajectory_controller
  - gripper_action_controller
  
arm_trajectory_controller:
  action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
  type: FollowJointTrajectory
  default: true
  joints:
    - lss_arm_joint_1
    - lss_arm_joint_2
    - lss_arm_joint_3
    - lss_arm_joint_4
    - lss_arm_joint_6

gripper_action_controller:
  action_ns: gripper_cmd
  type: GripperCommand
  default: true
  joints:
    - lss_arm_joint_5
    - lss_arm_joint_7

Setup:

Ros Humble
Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

I've tried what was written in here and asked the official forum, but I still haven't been able to solve the problem. The hole project is in my github

I'd try to separate your ros2_control project from moveit: Launch your simulation without moveit, and send a manual action request to gripper_action_controller: Does it work, is there any console output?

I've been trying to do this, but I usually end up breaking the whole project. I think that  maybe it's possible to create a node to publish to the gripper topic but I still haven't implemented this idea

I've discovered that if I execute some motions with the arm before trying to use the grippers, they start to work. I haven't been able to figured out why yet
